# Перенаправление с разных IP на разные домены в Apache

Tags: apache, apache2, virtual-hosts

Есть VDS с тремя адресами IP. Интерфейсы настроены, всё работает.
Требуется по аналогии с настройками `000-default.conf` сделать настройки для всех IP-адресов.

В `000-default.conf` делаю перенаправление с первого IP на первый домен (всё работает):

```
<VirtualHost FIRST_IP_HERE:80>
        ServerAdmin name@example.com
        ServerName FIRST_IP_HERE
        Redirect 301 / http://FIRST_DOMAIN_HERE/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Пробую по аналогии сделать перенаправление с другого IP, на другой домен, но перенаправление при обращении по второму IP всё равно идёт на домен из `000-default.conf`.

Пробовал как скопировать описание виртуального хоста в файле `000-default.conf` (изменив IP и домен), так и создать файл `001-default.conf` и сделать для него `a2ensite`. Ничего не помогает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, могу ли я настроить apache так, чтобы при обращении на `FIRST_IP` шло перенаправление на `FIRST_DOMAIN`, при обращении на `SECOND_IP` - перенаправление на `SECOND_DOMAIN` и т. д., и если могу - то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не смог воспроизвести вашу проблему. На локальной машине успешно перенаправляло на разные домены.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.10:80>
        ServerAdmin name@example.com
        ServerName 127.0.0.10
        Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.11:80>
        ServerAdmin name@example.com
        ServerName 127.0.0.11
        Redirect 301 / http://example.net/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Думаю, следует внимательно прочитать [документацию по `vhosts`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) и посмотреть аналогичные вопросы на английском SO.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ! Действительно, теперь всё работает. Когда проверял днём с работы - не работало, а сейчас из дома работает и в варианте с несколькими файлами, и в варианте с одним файлом `000-default.conf`.